# Problema em implementar icone do font awesome pelo css

Tags: css, html5, font-awesome, scss

estou com um problema em carregar minha font via `css` estou usando o `font awesome 5` eu estou implementando os icones via `content` no `css` porém o icone que eu quero usar não está funcionando esse seria o link do icone que quero usar [F0da](https://fontawesome.com/icons/caret-right?style=solid) mais ele não quer aparecer e o mais  engraçado é que se uso esse code por exemplo aparece `f007` não sei oque pode ser segue meu código para analize e link de `import` da biblioteca de icones:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.10/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-+d0P83n9kaQMCwj8F4RJB66tzIwOKmrdb46+porD/OvrJ+37WqIM7UoBtwHO6Nlg" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
                    <span class="text-uppercase text-white">Categoria</span>
                    <ul class="nav flex-column links-categories">
                        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Açougues<span>(45)</span></a></a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Adegas e bebidas<span>(64)</span></a></a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Água Mineral<span>(49)</span></a></a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Avícolas<span>(52)</span></a></a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Bar e lanches<span>(214)</span></a></a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Bombonieres<span>(7)</span></a></a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Buffets<span>(33)</span></a></a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Cafeterias<span>(68)</span></a></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
```

SCSS:

```
.links-categories{
      li{
        position: relative;
        &:before{
          content:"\f0da";
          font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
          position: absolute;
          left: -20px;
          top: 0;
          color: $orange;

        }
        a{
          font-size: 14px;
          padding: 0;
        }
      }
    }
```

aqui vai o print de como fica o icone caret que quero usar:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui] 
ele não funciona porem se uso esse codigo aqui `f007` ele funciona:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não poderia ser com o FontAwesome 4?

Comment: @hugocsl então e que ja começei com o 5 to tentando usar tudo de mais atual nesse projeto até to usando a versão nova do bootstrap hehehe tem ideia do que possa ser ?

Comment: Consegui fazer com a versão 5 mesmo, tinha uns detalhes na documentação. É meio complicado mas deu certo :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Acrescente isto no seu CSS:

```
font-weight: 900;
```

Pelo que vejo, esse caractere só está disponível nessa fonte bold. Não entendi o motivo, vai ver é porque ele é `f0da` :D

Comment: +1 pela explicação em hexadecimal :)

Answer (score 1):

Conforme a documentação para vc usar no `::before` vc tem que ajustar algumas coisas. Vc vai precisar usar o `fontawesome.js` e não o `.css` pois só vai funcionar com a font no formato SVG. Depois vc tem que chamar o script deles e fazer umas customizações no seu css. [Link da documentação](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/svg-with-js)

Então primeiro chame o CDN em `.js`:

```
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.12/js/all.js"></script>
```

Depois o script:

```
<script>
    FontAwesomeConfig = { searchPseudoElements: true };
</script>
```

Agora veja funcionando já como o CSS pronto.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.12/js/all.js"></script>
    <script>
        FontAwesomeConfig = { searchPseudoElements: true };
    </script>
<style>
    body {
        margin-left: 20px;
    }
    .links-categories li {
        position: relative;
    }
    .links-categories a {
        font-size: 14px;
        padding: 0;
    }
    /* estilos do ::before*/
    .links-categories li::before {
        display: none;
    }
    .links-categories li::before {
        font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Solid";
        content: "\f0da";
    }
    .nav .svg-inline--fa {
        color: orange !important;
        position: absolute;
        left: -20px;
        top: 3px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    
<div class="col-md-4">
    <span class="text-uppercase text-white">Categoria</span>
    <ul class="nav flex-column links-categories">
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Açougues<span>(45)</span></a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Adegas e bebidas<span>(64)</span></a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Água Mineral<span>(49)</span></a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Avícolas<span>(52)</span></a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Bar e lanches<span>(214)</span></a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Bombonieres<span>(7)</span></a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Buffets<span>(33)</span></a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Cafeterias<span>(68)</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

        
    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```